# Proxy blocking uploads

Tags: php, file-upload, proxy, uploadify

I am using uploadify to upload files on a site. Every once and a while I get these errors in my server log:

```
[Tue Jun 26 09:24:45 2012] [error] [client ipaddress] Handler for x-httpd-php5 returned  invalid result code 70007
[Tue Jun 26 09:25:17 2012] [error] [client ipaddress] Handler for x-httpd-php5 returned invalid result code 70014
```

After some googling I have found that is probably caused by a person using a proxy when they are on our site.

I read somewhere online that this may help:

```
pass your apache log in debug mode using the directive LogLevel
```

I don't know what that means but i can pass it along to my webhost.

Is there any way to try and detect a proxy so I can warn the user that the upload may fail?

Any other ideas on how to handle this?

Has anyone else had this issue with uploading files via a proxy?

Comment: FYI- I am using php as my server side language

Comment: I also just found that this maybe the cause: internet-providers with poor transferrate/proxy, any way to detect that?

Comment: Can you describe what makes your HTTP server insert the number into the logs? Or asked differently: Where does that invalid result code number that is inserted into the HTTPD logs comes from?

Comment: Not sure. How would I find that out?